# Eclipse: Can I Dock The "Open Resource" Dialog?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2
( what comes with and is integrated into WebLogic 11g )

Is it possible to dock the "Open Resource" dialog box ( ctrl + shift + r )?

I'm migrating over from another IDE.  I'm used to/am looking for something like that "Open Resource" dialog being docked on the left side, where I can just type the name of a file to get it..........without having to go to a menu or opening up a dialog box.

Is there such a thing in Eclipse?

If not, is there a plugin that will do something similar?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't exactly what I asked for in the original post, but "ctrl + f" in package explorer or project explorer makes a text book appear in those windows for typing in a file name.

Much more convenient, like my old work flow, than ctrl+shift+r to invoke an entire dialog box and then type.

It is available on Linux, not Windows

**From Bug (Report) 408375:**

> The search field is only available on operating systems that support
>   this, e.g. some Linux variants. Windows does not support this.
>
> See bug 69200 for a generic solution in Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Generally, if you can invoke that functionality via a keyboard shortcut *from everywhere*, there is no benefit in having an alternative implementation which consumes screen space and where the view must be focused first to run the same command.

Other alternatives are the "Navigate" main menu, or the toolbar, where you can place a button for that functionality (using the "Customize perspective" menu).